# Discord Bot not coming online

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm using Visual Studio Code for my bot. I just started and I can't get my bot to come online. This is my code

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-')

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print('YEEEEEEEEET')
    
client.run('BOT_TOKEN')
```

I'm following tutorial from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nW8c7vT6Hl4

Comment: I think you need to change your `command_prefix`: `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')`

Comment: what do i need to change it to

Comment: You have a dash. In the tutorial, there is a dot: `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')`.

Comment: I tried dot it still doesn't work.

Comment: What errors are thrown?

Comment: stop relying on video tutorials and read the actual documentation. videos gets outdated easily (might not be the case here). 

from a quick search, check the example from the official documentation here: 
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#basic-concepts

also make sure your token is right: https://discord.com/developers/applications

Comment: do you get error ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: BTW: code works for me if I use my token.

Comment: On your file, did you use the token that you made on the dev portal for discord? or did you use `'BOT_TOKEN'`? You have to make sure that your token is accurate. Also, the command_prefix doesn't matter when creating a bot. Just because the video did it that way, doesn't mean that you always have to use the same thing.

Comment: It was a certificate problem with my windows, it worked when I installed the certificate from discord

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a bot and generate a token following: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discord.html

Comment: I did have a token, I just didn't want to show it. I solved the problem! it was a certificate problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was a certificate problem, and not problem with the code.