# Discord bot not coming online, possible certificate error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I wanted to try my hand at making a discord bot however I'm running into an issue where my bot will not come online. I've tried 2 different codes I've found from internet tutorials but neither of them will make the bot appear online or do anything. I've seen someone ask a similar question on here using a similar code to what I have implemented and was currently working with and said that their issues were coming from a certificate error ([Discord Bot not coming online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625377/discord-bot-not-coming-online)) but I'm not sure how I would go about resolving it. For context I'm using `Python 3.9` on `PyCharm` and my code looks like this (I have used an actual token but I've heard its not good to give that out) :

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot is ready')

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Please ask if you need any more information that what I've already provided.

edit1:pycharm says that the import 'import discord' is unused is that why im having issues?

edit2:I have tried using the following command to get the bot to do something but it is still not working-

```
@client.event

async def ping(ctx):
    
    await ctx.send('pong!')
```

Comment: try adding some commands and report back if those work.

Comment: Everything looks fine, how long have you been waiting? Do you get any errors?

Comment: looks ok this far. Have you added the redirect URI in the OAuth2 section of the application management?

Comment: I tried to add some code using the @client.event where it would send a message when someone joined the server, I then added another bot to try and trigger the event but nothing happened

Comment: Pycharm doesn’t say that there are any errors in the code if that’s what you mean

Comment: I haven’t put anything as the redirect url in OAuth2, is there something I need to be putting in there?

Comment: add some other function to bot. `on_ready` doesn't have to be executed when bot is ready but when new user connect to bot.

Comment: run it in without PyCharm. If it doesn't display anything then it is working without problem.  When I run it then never display `bot is ready` but it doesn't matter. But if I try some command on my discord server - ie. `.test` - then  bot display warning that it doesn't know this command - and I know that it is working.

Comment: if you know similar question then you could add link in your question.

Comment: i have tried adding the command that ive edited into the post but the bot still remains inactive

Comment: the similar post i mentioned is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625377/discord-bot-not-coming-online

Comment: by run it without pycharm do you mean put the base code into the python terminal, if so i was given a load of errors when i tried it saying that there was no module named 'discord'.

Comment: yes, I means run in system console/terminal/cmd.exe like `python script.py`. If you get error `no module 'discord'` then you have two Python installed and one (in PyCharm) has installed `discord` but other (in terminal) doesn't have it. You may need `pip install discord.py` or safer `python -m pip install discord.py

Comment: as I said before `on_ready` may not work but bot can be OK - better to add some command and check if bot will react when you use command in discord. Eventually you can create `on_connect` instead of `on_ready`. If bot doesn't display any error then we can't recognize what can be problem - it should display any error message when there is real problem.